# UIMA Ruta wordlist case ignore

Tags: uima, ignore-case, ruta

My use case is such that i have a list of match words in a WORDLIST "MonthNames.txt".

Now i want to Mark all the occurrences of these words in the given document irrespective of the text case.

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

WORDLIST MonthNameList = 'MonthNames.txt';
DECLARE MonthNames;
DECLARE MonthNameValue;


// Regex to be used in finding dates
STRING monthNameValueRegex = "(?i)(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|jun|jul|aug|sept|oct|nov|dec)";


// Mark month name


Document{-> MARKFAST(MonthNames, MonthNameList)};

Document{CONTAINS(MonthNames) -> MARK(MonthNameValue)};


 Document{REGEXP(monthNameValueRegex) -> MARK(MonthNameValue)};
```

Is there any way to do it ?

I tried

```
Document{-> MARKFAST(MonthNames, MonthNameList,true)};
```

But that is just to ignore whitespaces not text case.

Please help

Comment: The doc says "The third parameter is optional. It defines, whether the MARKFAST action should ignore the case, whereby its default value is false."

Comment: The whitespaces should be ignored by default if you are using the normal filtering settings. The argument of MARKFAST should do the trick. If it doesn't, then there might be another problem. Then, you could maybe post more information, like a reproducible example.

Comment: Normal regular expressions can be used the following way: "(?i)(january|february)" -> MonthNameValue;    The last two rules in your example won't work as you expect as they try to annotate the complete document with one annotation.

Comment: I intend to ignore text case. If "MonthNames.txt" contains an entry january, i want to mark "JANUARY","January","JaNuArY" etc.

Comment: Also its quite cumbersome to maintain a RegEx for this purpose. Please suggest.

Comment: What you tried (MARKFAST) should work just fine. I will test it again. What version of UIMA Ruta do you use?

Comment: oh yes! Sorry i got confused another annotation. It works. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a 3rd variable as true makes it ignore the word case.

Document{-> MARKFAST(MonthNames, MonthNameList,true)};

Thanks to Peter for his help.